# rsync not working with apache tomcat

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat

I have java spring application on amazon ec2 running on apache tomcat6 server . I need to copy the file between this amazon ec2 and another server. For that I trying with  rysnc . In terminal it is working. But when I tried with my script it is not working. How can I fix this problem? I am running this on apache tomcat6 server . Any help highly appreciable. Where exactly I need to put the .ssh file to execute this.

Comment: what is it that's not working?

Comment: Can you ssh into the other server as the tomcat user?

Comment: What is "your script"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some research I find the answer myself. But I was late to write it here. This may help some others

Inorder to exectue the rsync command from the java spring application file, first I setup the auto ssh login between my ec2 server and another cloud server.To create this, I followed these steps

On amazon ec2 server ,

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Then copied the authorized key to cloud server

```
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh <user>@<server ip> "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

alternatively we can use

```
ssh-copy-id <user>@<ip>
```

Then tried to login to  server

```
   ssh <user>@<server ip>
```

This time it wont ask for password for login

Next step is I have to place the .ssh inside the /usr/share/tomcat6

```
sudo cp -r /home/<user_name>/.ssh/ /usr/share/tomcat6
sudo chown -R tomcat6:tomcat6 .ssh/
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart
```

Then tried to execute the file containing rsync command . It worked :)